# Setting a variable from FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have the following for loop

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in ("%FORMS60_PATH%") do (
        echo %%a | findstr /i /r SAM
    )
```

what it does is read a registry key, FORMS60_PATH.
the registry key as the value - c:\sam;c:\sape

It searchs the key if it has SAM in it and returns c:\sam if valid
The question is ...how can I set this value to a variable?

Comment: Type `set /?` in you console

Comment: I do know what the set command does ...I just don't know how to set the value I get in the findstr ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in ("%FORMS60_PATH%") do (
        echo %%a | findstr /i /r SAM && (
           set "variable=%%a"
        )
    )
echo %variable%
```

?

Comment: Please provide some kind of explanations too while answering questions

Comment: No because the %%a value is the full path that comes from the FOR loop, not the 'modified' by the findstr one ...

Comment: @PedroSales What is the content of the line and what part you want to set to a variable

Comment: the line has
c:\sam;c:\sape
with the FOR I get c:\sam, and that's what I want